# Azure asp.net web app trying to connect to Oracle runtime integration linked service

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, azure, cloud

I've created both a `web app service` and a data factory with a runtime integration linked service to `Oracle`(connection tested and working) on Azure.  The `web app service` is `asp.net core` and written in c#.

Question is: How do I establish a connection from the web app service to this Oracle linked service connection?

Using `odbc connection`, I can connect locally from my computer to the `oracle database` using this string format:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

How do I reference the Oracle linked service in this c# code though? (is it possible?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Hybrid connection** to connect azure web app to oracle server by following the below steps:

To create a Hybrid Connection, go to the Azure portal and select your App Service, then select  **Networking**  >  **Configure your Hybrid Connection endpoints**.

[image]

[image]

Click on the  **Add hybrid connection**  as shown in the previous screenshot, and you’ll see the following screen:

[image]

Click on  **Create new hybrid connection**  link and the following blade will show:

[image]

In the **Create new hybrid connection** blade, you must fill in the following fields for your Oracle server hybrid connection:

Once you click on  **OK**  button, Azure will start creating your hybrid connection.
Notice that after creation the  **status**  of the hybrid connection is “**Not connected**” in the screenshot below.

This is okay as we did not deploy the HCM or establish the connectivity yet.

[image]

To complete our hybrid connection setup, we must download and install the Hybrid Connection Manager (HCM) from the link in the portal:

[image]

Once you have downloaded the package, run it and perform following steps:

Click on the  **Install**  button

Open the **Hybrid Connection Manager UI**:

[image: Machine generated alternative text: Hybrid Connection Manager UI App]

Click on the  **Add a new Hybrid Connection**  link, login to your Azure subscription and choose the subscription that you created the hybrid connection under.

Once logged in, you should see the following window:

[image: Machine generated alternative text: Configure New Hybrid Connections Subscription oracleserverl sqlserverl Cancel REGION southcentralus southcentralus SERVICE NAME oracleServer1ServiceBus sqlServerServiceBus1 ENDPOINT ora-server-1:1521 sql-server-l: 1433 Enter Manually]

[image: Machine generated alternative text: C?) Hybrid Connection Manager About AZURE STATUS Add a new Hybrid Connection oracleserverl sq Iserverl Not Connected Not Connected SERVICE NAME oracleserverlservicebus sqlserverservicebusl ENDPOINT ora-server-1:1521 sql-server-l : 1433 Enter Manually x Refresh]

To change the status to connected you need to restart the  **Azure Hybrid Connection Manager Service**

Here is the HCM window after the service restart or computer reboot:

[image: Machine generated alternative text: C?) Hybrid Connection Manager About AZURE STATUS Add a new Hybrid Connection oracleserverl sq Iserverl Connected Connected SERVICE NAME oracleserverlservicebus sqlserverservicebusl ENDPOINT ora-server-1:1521 sql-server-l : 1433 Enter Manually x Refresh]

Here is the hybrid connection status in the Azure Portal after the service restart or computer reboot:

[image]

**Note**: we cannot install the Oracle client on Azure App Services. But we have to use  **Oracle Managed Data Access**.

You need to reference the Oracle Managed Data Access from NuGet:

[image: Machine generated alternative text: O Oracle.ManagedDataAccess by Oracle The official Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver for Oracle Database. vi9.6.o X]

Use the following namespace in your .NET application:

[image]

Another important change is needed: the Oracle connection string.
If you use the old connection string, then it will not work when you publish it to Azure App Services. Here is how your Oracle connection string should look:

> connectionString =  "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
> TCP)(HOST = ora-server-1)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER =
> DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.internal))));User
> Id=walid;Password=xyz;"

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, thanks for your reply.  I was able to get it connected but it's throwing an error of "Error:ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file" when I try to establish connection.  Would you know why this might be?